# CPU cache sets and address bits

Tags: cpu-cache

I have some questions about CPU caches I would like some clarification on.
Assume that I have a 128 KB cache with a block size of 64. It is 4-way associative.

1. How many sets does the cache have?
2. How many bits are used for the offset, index, and tag, assuming that the CPU provides 32-bit addresses?
3. How large is the tag array?

Comment: 1) How big is each set? 2) What does each part need to single out? 3) How many tags do you need?

Comment: Since all concepts and relevant formulas should have been explained in your textbook/lectures notes or by your instructor, it is expected of you to explain *why and where* you need clarification.  Otherwise, this question will be likely to be closed.